# Using ResourceDictionary in Resources of the UserControl vs. Resources of the Element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have a ResourceDictionary with the following source:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dict">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
                        Source="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have a style for textboxes in there that I want to use inside a Grid. When I use the Resource in the `<Grid.Resources>`-Tag everything works fine and I can use the Style with `Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}`. However, when I move the Resource to the `<UserControl.Resources>`-Tag, the Styles can no longer be resolved (even after cleaning and compiling new).

I have not found any information on to why this happens. Can anybody help me here?

Comment: can you show the code of your `UserControl`?

Comment: It is quite a big UserControl, but it is structured like this:

```<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
           <ResourcesPart>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Style={StaticResource someResource}> 
               ...
```
Intrestingly, if I remove all the other Resources so I do not need a key any longer, the Resource can be resolved. So maybe I need to use the key somewhere in the Style Property?

Sorry also, I haven't seen the notification.